# CNTK python API: Dynamic Axis construction for CNN+LSTM-Network

Tags: python, regression, conv-neural-network, lstm, cntk

I'm working on a Regression problem on video/image sequence input with CNTK Python API.
Input data is a (minibatch_size x sequence_length x channel x height x width)-tensor with (at this time) fixed minibatch_size = 1, sequence_length = 3 and only 1 channel. Output data is a (minibatch_size x sequence_length x num_landmarks) tensor with exactly the same sequence length. A CNN+LSTM network then analyzes one video frame and outputs 26 landmarks.
My network is defined as follows:

```
def create_network_definition(model_func):

    # define dynamic axes
    batch_axis = Axis.default_batch_axis()
    input_seq_axis = Axis('inputAxis')
    label_seq_axis = Axis('labelAxis')

    # construct input variables
    input_dynamic_axes = [batch_axis, input_seq_axis]
    input_var = input_variable(shape=(video_channel_count, video_height, video_width), dynamic_axes=input_dynamic_axes, dtype=np.float32)

    label_dynamic_axes = [batch_axis, label_seq_axis]
    label_var = input_variable(shape=(num_landmarks), dynamic_axes=label_dynamic_axes, dtype=np.float32)

    # instantiate 2D Convolution network
    z = model_func(input_var, out_dims = num_landmarks)

    # loss and metric
    loss = squared_error(z, label_var)
    error = sqrt(constant(1/num_landmarks) * loss)

    return {
        'input'  : input_var,
        'label'  : label_var,
        'loss'   : loss,
        'error'  : error, 
        'output' : z
    }
```

This envokes following error:

```
Training so far unspecified number of parameters in 7 parameter tensors.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Conv2D_300VW_v1.py", line 490, in <module>
    gen_heartbeat      = False)
  File "Conv2D_300VW_v1.py", line 457, in do_training_and_validation
    trainer = create_trainer(network, epoch_size, max_epochs, minibatch_size, progress_printer)
  File "Conv2D_300VW_v1.py", line 357, in create_trainer
    learner  = momentum_sgd(network['output'].parameters, lr_schedule, mm_schedule) #, l2_regularization_weight=l2_reg_weight)
  File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\cntk\internal\swig_helper.py", line 63, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\site-packages\cntk\learners\__init__.py", line 499, in momentum_sgd
    additional_options)
ValueError: Cannot create an NDArrayView using a view shape '[? x 26]' that has unknown dimensions for any of its axes.

[CALL STACK]
    > CNTK::NDArrayView::  DeepClone
    - CNTK::NDArrayView::NDArrayView<double>
    - CNTK::NDArrayView::  NDArrayView
    - CNTK::Value::  GetSequenceStartsAndLengths
    - CNTK::Value::  GetSequenceStartsAndLengths
    - CNTK::Variable::operator std::shared_ptr<CNTK::Function>
    - CNTK::Value::  GetSequenceStartsAndLengths
    - RtlRunOnceExecuteOnce
    - InitOnceExecuteOnce
    - _crtInitOnceExecuteOnce
    - CNTK::Value::  GetSequenceStartsAndLengths
    - CNTK::Variable::  Value
    - CNTK::Internal::  SaveAsLegacyModel
    - CNTK::  AdamLearner
    - CNTK::Internal::  ZeroesWithDynamicAxesLike
    - CNTK::Internal::  ZeroesWithDynamicAxesLike
```

I suspect that the learner fails to get the batch size and the sequence size from the data. But why? How do I have to implement the dynamic axes correctly? I cannot find any hint in CNTK documentation.

I also tried setting both `dynamic_axes=input_dynamic_axes` as well as `input_seq_axis = Axis.default_dynamic_axis()` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

input and label dynamic axis need to be the same. As follow:

```
input_dynamic_axes = [batch_axis, input_seq_axis]  
label_dynamic_axes = [batch_axis, input_seq_axis]
```